# ASM Get cart is making two HTTP request without passing authentication header

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I created a Spartacus project with authentication configure using 'asm'. I used asmAuth.authorizeCustomerSupportAgent() to log in, and used OCC API:

```
GET /{baseSiteId}/users/{userId}/carts/{cartId}
```

to get a cart with a given a user and a cart id.

However, when I make the GET request, I found out in my Network that I am actually making 2 requests. One is with the URL that I gave, the other is

```
/{baseSiteId}/users/{userId}/carts/{cartId}?fields=DEFAULT,potentialProductPromotions,appliedProductPromotions,potentialOrderPromotions,appliedOrderPromotions,entries(totalPrice(formattedValue),product(images(FULL),stock(FULL)),basePrice(formattedValue),updateable),totalPrice(formattedValue),totalItems,totalPriceWithTax(formattedValue),totalDiscounts(value,formattedValue),subTotal(formattedValue),deliveryItemsQuantity,deliveryCost(formattedValue),totalTax(formattedValue),pickupItemsQuantity,net,appliedVouchers,productDiscounts(formattedValue),user'
```

The first request returned the cart successfully. The second request returns 401 Full Authentication is required error. Apparently, the authentication header was not passed into this second request.

I am wondering why is there 2 request, and if this is cause of the defaultOccCartConfig that came with Spartacus. If it is, how can I either disable it or pass in the authentication header?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I fully understand your use case since it seems like you are not using the out of the box ASM implementation and perhaps also involves some custom code you are developing.

I doubt this behaviour is related to `defaultOccCartConfig`: this `const` contains the configuration for the urls of the endpoints, but no configuration that influences the number of calls.

I can give you an overview of some ASM logic that may be relevant to your case and may help you troubleshoot.

Yes, to begin, the customer support agent needs to sign in with `AsmAuthService.authorizeCustomerSupportAgent()`

In order to perform occ requests on the behalf of a customer, you need to start a customer emulation session via AsmAuthService.startCustomerEmulationSession(). You need to provide the agent’s token and customer id for that.  See:

```
AsmAuthService.startCustomerEmulationSession()
```

https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/blob/release/1.4.x/projects/core/src/asm/facade/asm-auth.service.ts#L42

Once the customer emulation session is started, the `UserTokenInterceptor` should assign an authentication header to all outgoing occ requests, just like it does for regular customer sessions:

```
UserTokenInterceptor
```

https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/blob/release/1.4.x/projects/core/src/auth/http-interceptors/user-token.interceptor.ts#L20-L42